# Vivado gives confusing result

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, vivado

I'm working on a prime calculation project which is to be implemented using Verilog on a Zybo board. I'm currently facing a strange problem and looking for a method to way forward.
I have implemented an FSM with 12 states. In my FSM, I set a register called 'flag' to LOW at state 'S2' and it is set to HIGH at state 'S10'.  All simulations, including Post-implementation Timing Simulation, give results as expected. However, when implemented on the hardware it doesn't give expected results. After many days of troubleshooting, I found(using Integrated Logic Analyzer) that the register 'flag' stays HIGH only at state 'S10'. It works like I had assigned a default value for 'flag' as ZERO and change to HIGH when it is at state 'S10'.  But that is not what I have coded. Any idea or suggestion to solve this issue would be highly appreciated.

The relevant Verilog code is given below.

```
// Output logic
always@(*) begin
    idle_reg = 0;
    ld_A = 0;
    ld_n = 0;
    ld_i = 0;
    ld_P = 0;
    clr = 0;
    start_mod = 0;
    prime_found = 0;
    done = 0;
    case(state)
        WAIT: begin
            idle_reg = 1;
            clr = 1;
        end 
        S1: begin
            ld_A = 1;
            ld_n = 1;
        end 
        S2: begin
            flag = 1'b0;
            ld_n = 1;
        end 
        S5: begin
            ld_i = 1;
        end 
        S7: begin
            start_mod = 1;
        end 
        S10: begin
            flag = 1'b1;
        end 
        S11: begin
            prime_found = 1;
            ld_P = 1;
        end 
        DONE: begin
            done = 1;
        end 
    endcase 
end
```

Comment: You are only showing us a tiny portion of the code. And it may be your testbench that is actually producing incorrect output rather than the real world. What does your testbench look like?

Comment: Hmm FSM without clock. Maybe you should first google the full of FSM. Specifically the letter 'S'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a "state machine"; **Change "always@(*) begin" to "always @(posedge clk) begin"**. 
Your "// Output logic" is concurrent with "always@(*) begin" and deserved to get immediate result of '0'. Meantime the "case()" is missing default case/state that can cover either concurrent or sequential behavior. 
*It's been a while since last using Verilog. Please pardon me if the syntax error occurs.*

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, I've shown the segment of code where 'flag' is assigned values. The full FSM  has a sequential block and two combinational blocks. One combinational block is for 'next state' logic and the other combinational block, which is shown here, is for generating outputs(it may not need a 'default' as I have included it in the other combinational block). The sequential block has 'always @(posedge clk)'. By the way, assigning a value to 'flag' prior to 'case' (default value)will not produce the desired result.

Comment: @SusanthaWijesinghe , Could the problem be out side of this "Output logic"?

Comment: Yes (see above) always @(*) makes stuff that synthesises into wires, or sometimes latches (but never flops) even if they are declared as "reg" in verilog - normally we'd expect all of the things assigned in such a block to end up as wires - however because you are not defining 'flag' for every case there (there isn't a default define at the beginning) verilog simulation for it is going to result in latch-like behaviour - vivado may or may not be able to infer a latch there (which I'm sure is not what you expect)

Comment: Jay and Taniwha are genious people. You pointed exactly at where the problem was. Once I changed the 'output logic' to 'always @(posedge clk)' and registered the outputs, the problem vanished, and the system worked as expected. Thanks again for your valuable idea. I would like to thanks all people who commented on this issue.